# Are there pitfalls to using a db table with 400 columns that maps to an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, database

I have to work with a legacy MySQL database that, for reasons outside of my control, can not be normalised.

- The db consists of one table with 400 columns of various types
- The table has 2,000 rows, and grows by 300 per week
- Basic calculations like averages and counts will be carried out
- The data are graphed across varying time series, and presented on a dashboard (built in Rails)
- I can change the type of database (to Postgresql or MongoDB), but I can not alter the structure of the table.
- New data will be uploaded via CSV file
- No data validation is required
- There are no joins

I've worked with Rails for sometime, but I've never created a model with more than 15 or 20 columns. My concerns are:

1. Performance implications, if any, of an ActiveRecord model with 400 attributes.
2. Would using json data type in Postgresql or using MongoDB be a better fit given the data is not relational?
3. I'm under the impression that SQL databases excel at calculations, and I'm concerned that using JSON would add performance or complexity overhead when making calculations on the data.

Comment: This is a question which mixes objective & subjective concerns. Performance implications are relative - you're probably aware that when loading an AR model with 400 attributes, you're causing a considerable amount of memory overhead. JSON data types (including JSONb with GIN indexes in PostgreSQL) may be a good fit - but then again, maybe not, due to your query requirements. Basically, it depends on your use case, there's no hands-down right answer.

Comment: @Momer I don't think there's much that is subjective here. I'd like to know if anyone attempted this before, and what useful lessons, if any, they can share about their experience. My usecase is clearly detailed.

Comment: @Momer have a read of this. http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php

Comment: I was not the only on to flag this as opinion based. I'm sorry that you took offense, but it is opinion based.

Comment: @Momer thank you, but there's no need to apologise. You are entitled to your opinion as I am. I feel that the rules have become very rigid on SO. I've already seen examples where people have closed questions without fulling reading them to see the subtle but all important differences (and once they did they backtracked). I think many people cast close votes because they see someone else has already cast one, without really paying attention. I don't see how closing my question protects the quality of SO. Indeed many people saw fit to upvote it.